# Interest rate risk calculation for Banking book

Tags: interest-rates, risk

There is a detailed discussions on the *Interest rate risk for Banking book*. For Floating rate bond, this states like below -

> such positions generate cash flows that are not predictable past the
> next repricing date other than that the present value would be reset
> to par. Accordingly, such instruments can be treated as a series of
> coupon payments until the next repricing and a par notional cash flow
> at the time bucket midpoint closest to the next reset date bucket.

Assume that, the regulator also defines the time buckets as `O/N, O/N-4m, 4m-9M, 9M-2Y, 2Y-10Y` etc.

My questions are as below -

1. Let consider a non-standard floating rate bond with coupon payment frequency as `6-months`, which pays rate as average of `O/N` rates during the relevant period. Or, a bond which pays coupon based on `Libor` plus some spread. Typically, such bonds will be priced at **Par only if coupon rate is same as discount rate**. Therefore, for above bonds, how the statement "present value would be reset to par" will be valid?
2. How exactly the slotting onto time-bucket would happen in practice? Let say, the bond's coupon frequency is `6M` and matured at `1Y` from today. So the 1st coupon payment will fall on the slot of `4m-9M`. So to calculate the risk, should I assume, it's effective maturity is `4M` (as it is closer to the actual maturity of 6M)? Or the mid-point as 6.5m for all PV and other calculations?

Any insight will be highly appreciated.